# How can I define x(t) in terms of n?(matlab)

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals

I have a signal x[n], that is sum of two sinusoidal signals. $x(t)=sin(2100t)+0.7cos(2500t)$

```
fs = 5000; %sampling frequency
N=250;     %number of samples for 50ms time portion
ts=1/fs;   %time interval between samples
t = linspace(0,0.05,N);%time domain from 0 to 0.05s(50ms) with 250 samples

x =  sin(2*pi*100*t)+0.7*cos(2*pi*500*t);
```

I created a 50ms portion of this signal with 5kHz sampling frequency to get x[n]. And for random y[n],

How can I implement the below equation in MATLAB?

[image]

Comment: $$ x[n] = x(t)\Big|_{t=\frac{n}{f_\mathrm{s}}} $$

Comment: `NMSE = sum((x-y).^2/x.^2)`

Comment: `y = rand(size(x)); nmse = sum((x - y).^2./x.^2);`

Comment: Questions requesting working code written to a specification are off-topic as they are unlikely to benefit anyone else. Instead, describe the problem you're solving and where you're stuck. Since this feels like a very basic Matlab programming task, make sure you've read the matlab tutorial (it's included with matlab!) and are able to generally implement things like sums, squares, and use indices. There's very little about this that's dsp.